# Getting Data from 2 tables with same user id in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm using MYSQL
I have a table name "Transaction" which have 10 columns in it and there is another table name "user" which have 10 columns in it.
Now what i want is to get the some data from Transaction table and some data from User table.
for eg, I want data like

```
name,srname,age 
from 'transaction' table 
& i want phone number from 'user' table
```

"UserID is common in both the table"

Comment: Please would you read, [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)
and amend your question accordingly.

Comment: This is really fairly basic SQL. Do you have a real attempt, seeing that usually clarifies a number of things to us

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
select t.srname,t.age from `transaction` t inner join `user` u on t.userid = u.userId
```